# Update Manager reports ~2GB of updates after changing some settings

Tags: updates, update-manager, settings, restore

How do I reset the Update Manager settings so then I can make a small update?

I was configuring the settings and now the Update Manager finds 1.9GB of updates, and that's too much for my Internet connection. It did find 200MB before, but then I was just messing around with the settings and that happened.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you enable proposed and backports,  try unsetting them.

Start Update Manager - Settings, when you get Software Settings open go to the Update tab and check.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Updates_Tab

Answer (score 0):

Or it is possible that it ran an update and grabbed all the new files info from the repository that do in fact have updates. The equivalent of `sudo apt-get update` may have occurred where it otherwise hadn't in quite some time.

If this is the case, you can deselect what you do not want to update using [Synaptic Package Manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto)